# Chrome Browser Push Notification For Web Application MVC

Tags: javascript, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-5, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement a browser push notification using chrome in my MVC Web Application.
I have followed [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en)

This is my manifest.json file

```
{
"name": "Push Demo",
"short_name": "Push Demo",
"display": "standalone",
"gcm_sender_id": "10XXXXXXXXXXX",
"gcm_user_visible_only": "true"
}
```

This is my sw.js file

```
    console.log('Started', self);
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    self.skipWaiting();
    console.log('Installed', event);
});
self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
    console.log('Activated', event);
});
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    console.log('Push message received', event);
    // TODO
});
```

This is my index.cshtml file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Push Notification codelab</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="~/manifest.json">

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Push Notification codelab</h1>
    <p>This page must be accessed using HTTPS or via localhost.</p>
    <button id="subscribeButton">Subscribe</button>        
</body>
</html>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { 
    var reg;
    var sub;
    var isSubscribed = false;        
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        console.log('Service Worker is supported');
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function () {
            return navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
        }).then(function (serviceWorkerRegistration) {
            reg = serviceWorkerRegistration;
            subscribeButton.disabled = false;
            console.log('Service Worker is ready :^)', reg);
            //alert(reg);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Service Worker Error :^(', error);
        });
    }


    $('#subscribeButton').click(function () {
        if (isSubscribed) {
                    unsubscribe();
                } else {
                    subscribe();
                }
    });



    function subscribe() {
        var gcm_sender_id = '';
        var gcm_user_visible_only = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/manifest.json",
            success: function (data) {                
                gcm_sender_id = data.gcm_sender_id;
            }
        });


        reg.pushManager.subscribe({ userVisibleOnly: true }).then(function (pushSubscription)
        {
            //alert(pushSubscription);
            sub = pushSubscription;
            console.log('Subscribed! Endpoint:', sub.endpoint);
            subscribeButton.textContent = 'Unsubscribe';
            isSubscribed = true;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Subscription Error :^(', error);
        });
    }
    function unsubscribe() {
        sub.unsubscribe().then(function (event) {
            subscribeButton.textContent = 'Subscribe';
            console.log('Unsubscribed!', event);
            isSubscribed = false;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error unsubscribing', error);
            subscribeButton.textContent = 'Subscribe';
        });
    }

    });
</script>
```

I am getting an error of

```
( DOMException: Registration failed - manifest empty or missing)
```

But I am able to view my manifest.json file from the link [localhost:6345/manifest.json](http://localhost:6345/manifest.json)

Please help me if I am missing any thing or doing any wrong steps. Please provide some answers or some another way to send browser push notification to user.
Thanks & Regards

Comment: can you add server side code?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. I had solved my problem with the help of a friend. Thanks for your Reply.

Comment: @ManishKumar Mind sharing how you fixed the problem? I'm in the same situation...

Comment: @RobertKoszewski my problem is fixed from a totally different approach. Can you share where you are stuck so that i can share some solution.

Comment: @ManishKumar Seems that in my case I didn't have the "gcm_sender_id" in the manifest.json file nor I knew where to get it from Firebase. Found the number and added it to the manifest.json file, and now everything seems to work. Your question actually made me notice the missing lines. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertKoszewski .. sounds good it helped you..